# JSlider being moved from an outside Object

Tags: java, swing, jslider

I am creating a simple "Play/rewind" interface for a simulation, with a JSlider that functions as both a Progress Bar and a Slider that you can move the simulation to any point in time within the simulation bounds.  The sliding to the point in time works perfectly, however I cannot get the actual slider to move while the simulation is "Playing".   Link to the GUI is shown below for added assistance:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rAWf.png

A simplified version of what I have going on

Main object has 2 objects, the GUI, and the Controller.
gui: Creates the slider/buttons and a Controller.  Slider's and Button's change/action listeners are set to the Controller

Controller: Various buttons that do the play/rewind functions.   This is handled through the use of a swing Timer that repaints the simulation every "Frame".   With the slider, the "CurrentFrame" is changed as you drag the slider across, and the repaint function is called.   What it is NOT doing is sliding itself while the timer is running.   Code for the stateChanged is below:

```
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent z) 
    {
        JSlider source = (JSlider)z.getSource();

        //If statement that checks if the state of the slider is done changing when the change listener is evoked
        if(!source.getValueIsAdjusting())
        {
            CurrentFrame = (int)source.getValue();
            colladaRoot.setPosition(framePos[CurrentFrame]);
            wwd.repaint();
        }
        // My attempt at checking if the timer is running, and changing the value of the slider
        // while it is.
        while (timer.isRunning())
            source.setValue(CurrentFrame);

    }
```

In case its requested, this is also the slider creating in the GUI class:

```
            JSlider framecontroller = new JSlider(0, LastFrame, CurrentFrame);
            framecontroller.addChangeListener(this.controller); 
            framecontroller.setMajorTickSpacing(200);
            framecontroller.setMinorTickSpacing(1);
            framecontroller.setPaintTicks(true);
            framecontroller.setPaintLabels(true);
```

Comment: If the update is relying on a change that is coming from within the change handler then your code is loopy and it is easy to get caught - bad idea.  First try changing the `while` to an `if` and see if that helps.

Comment: Put a print statement in your while loop of the value `CurrentFrame` and see if it works. This will help figure out if this is a synchronization issue or not.

Comment: @LiverpoolFTW Just tried what you sugested.  Its definitely not seeing the while loop, any thoughts?

Comment: You don't want to check the timer state from the ChangeEventListener, that only get fired when you move the slider. You need to add an ActionListener to the Timer and update the slider from there.

Comment: @Terryn Is it getting to the while loop and then skipping over it (check with print statements)? Are you updating timer.isRunning()? Are you using multithreading?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @LiverpoolFTW  I got the answer figured out.   The Slider needs to be updated in the action listeners when the timer goes off.  The changelistener only is called when something happens to the slider through mouse/keyboard/etc, and NOT when something inside the program modifies say the current frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to check the timer state from the `ChangeEventListener`, that only gets fired when you move the slider. You need to add an `ActionListener` to the `Timer` and update the slider from there

Comment: Trick is making sure the JSlider is part of the main class being created, so all subclasses (The GUI and the Controller) have access to it and can modify it's data values.

Thanks Devon!